# Read list in python

Tags: python, list

I have this list of lists that looks like this:

```
vrt = [[1,3,3,8,5,4,2,1,5,6],
       [2,4,3,3,6,8,1,3,5,6],    
       [4,5,6,4,7,4,3,6,4,7],
       [2,8,7,0,0,7,4,7,8,0],
       [2,3,4,7,0,8,7,6,3,8],
       [3,7,9,0,8,5,3,2,3,4],
       [1,5,7,7,6,4,2,3,5,6],
       [0,6,3,3,6,8,0,6,7,7],
       [0,1,3,2,8,0,0,0,0,0],
       [3,1,0,3,6,7,0,5,3,1],
       [1,3,5,7,0,8,6,5,3,1],
       [3,6,3,1,3,5,8,7,5,1],
       [4,3,6,0,0,8,4,7,5,3],
       [3,5,6,8,6,3,1,3,5,2]]
```

And I need to write a function that will read evey line, sum all the integers in every line and return the result of every line as new list, in case of this particular list result would be `[38, 41, 50...42]`, so just sum of every list.

Up till now I tried doing it like this

```
def po_vrstah(vrt):
    s = []
    line = vrt.read().split('\n')
    vsota = sum(line)
    s.append(vsota)
    return s
```

So I did a little research and apparently those read and split (`'\n'`) can be used only reading files I think?

So my question is, how can I use similar approach solving this problem? Is there a way to read lists in similar way as files?

Comment: yea, you are right `'\n'` is "newline" so for example `print("line1\nline2")` would print "line1" on the first line and "line2" on the second line. its a decent way to split up strings sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's much more simple:

```
>>> print map(sum, vrt)
```

Comment: So simple... I would have never thought of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[sum(lst) for lst in vrt]
```

or, if you are using Python 2, `map()` can be used as well:

```
map(sum, vrt)
```

You are correct that splitting on newlines is only useful for strings (whether read from a file or otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
your_sum = [sum(i) for i in vrt]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[sum(x) for x in vrt]
```

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
 def po_vrstah(vrt):
     return [sum(line) for line in vrt] # this is a list comprehension
```

this assigns each list in vrt to the variable line, one by one.
The variables in each list are then summed by sum(), and the result is appended to our list, sequentially.
To learn about list comprehensions, look [here](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html)